# How can I find out how many images I have in my assets in Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, assets

I do not know how many images I will have, whether there are any methods such as "assets.length" or other ways

```
ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: // here I have to specify how many images I have in my resource file
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return Container(
                          width: 100,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 25),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            image: DecorationImage(
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              image: AssetImage(
                                'assets/four_season/hotel${index}.jpg',
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
```

[image]

I will create many hotels, and it is unknown how many images there will be

Answer (score 4):

You can try this code block to work with,

```dart
Future<int> countFiles([
  String path = 'assets/images/',
]) async {
  final assetManifest = await AssetManifest.loadFromAssetBundle(rootBundle);
  final assetPaths = assetManifest
      .listAssets()
      .where((String key) => key.startsWith(path))
      .toList();

  debugPrint('Number of files in the $path folder: ${assetPaths.length}');
  return assetPaths.length;
}
```

Just call the function with proper path, if you select path for your case,
`assets` then the file count will be 10 (four_season's 4 & marriot_hotel's 6 files).

or if you select path `assets/four_season` then the count will be 4.

Comment: Be aware that accessing and reading AssetManifest.json isn't documented behavior. It isn't officially supported and could be broken at any time by an update to Flutter. You can use the [`AssetManifest.loadFromAssetBundle`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/AssetManifest/loadFromAssetBundle.html) API to load and read this file in a supported way.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewKolos I've updated my code.

Comment: @MeshkatShadik Thanks for the reply. I've been  for a long time, but I can't figure it out. Is the entries method used with the Map? if so, should I create a Map and what should it look like? I'm new to flutter, could you explain in more detail.

Comment: Actually it was my mistake to not updating the latest code, I feel apologize for that. Now I've updated my code.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to inspect what assets are available to your app at run time, the [listAssets](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/AssetManifest/listAssets.html) API is probably what you're looking for.

You can call this API, filter the resulting list however you please, and then inspect the `length` on the list.

Full sample application that lists all available assets:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MainApp());
}

class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: AssetManifest.loadFromAssetBundle(rootBundle),
            builder: (context, snapshot) => snapshot.hasData
                ? Column(
                    children: snapshot.data!
                        .listAssets()
                        .map((e) => Text(e))
                        .toList(),
                  )
                : const Text('Loading assets list...'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```